# How to substitute non printable characters with space character in a file

Tags: bash, text-processing, sed, replace, character-encoding

I have read nearly every answer about this topic on this website or Stackoverflow but didn't manage to solve the issue below.

When I copy the text from a PDF file and paste it into a text file [`file.txt`](https://file.io/e3z5XaFIep98)) , the text looks normal but when I use cat command:

```
cat -v file.txt
```

The output is:

```
vbox = None
M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- def __init__(self, title="Error!", parent=None,
M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- flags=Gtk.DialogFlags.MODAL, buttons=("NO",
M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- Gtk.ResponseType.NO, "_YES",
M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- Gtk.ResponseType.YES)):
M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- super().__init__(title=title, parent=parent, flags=flags,
M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- buttons=buttons)
M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- self.vbox = self.get_content_area()
M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- self.hbox = Gtk.Box(orientation=Gtk.Orientation.HORIZONTAL,
spacing=5)
M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- icon_theme = Gtk.IconTheme.get_default()
M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- icon = icon_theme.load_icon("dialog-question", 48,
M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- Gtk.IconLookupFlags.FORCE_SVG)
M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- image = Gtk.Image.new_from_pixbuf(icon)
M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- self.hbox.pack_start(image, False, False, 5)
M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- self.vbox.add(self.hbox)
M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- def set_message(self, message, add_msg=None):
M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- self.hbox.pack_start(Gtk.Label(message), False, False, 5)
M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- M-BM- if add_msg != None:
```

Or when I use [bat command](https://github.com/sharkdp/bat):

```
bat -A file.txt
```

The output is:

```
vbox•=•None␊
\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}def•__init__(self,•title="Error!",•parent=None,␊
\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}flags=Gtk.DialogFlags.MODAL,•buttons=("NO",␊
\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}Gtk.ResponseType.NO,•"_YES",␊
\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}Gtk.ResponseType.YES)):␊
\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}super().__init__(title=title,•parent=parent,•flags=flags,␊
\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}buttons=buttons)␊
\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}self.vbox•=•self.get_content_area()␊
\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}self.hbox•=•Gtk.Box(orientation=Gtk.Orientation.HORIZONTAL,␊
spacing=5)␊
\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}icon_theme•=•Gtk.IconTheme.get_default()␊
\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}icon•=•icon_theme.load_icon("dialog-question",•48,␊
\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}Gtk.IconLookupFlags.FORCE_SVG)␊
\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}image•=•Gtk.Image.new_from_pixbuf(icon)␊
\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}self.hbox.pack_start(image,•False,•False,•5)␊
\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}self.vbox.add(self.hbox)␊
\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}def•set_message(self,•message,•add_msg=None):␊
\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}self.hbox.pack_start(Gtk.Label(message),•False,•False,•5)␊
\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}\u{a0}if•add_msg•!=•None:␊
```

On Visual studio code, when I hover on those characters, I get:

```
The character U+00a0 is not a basic ASCII character.
```

[image]

How can I use sed command to replace those characters with normal "space" characters?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like the UTF-8 encoding of [the non-breaking space (U+00A0)](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+00A0), the bytes are `c2 a0` in hex. Something like `sed -e 's/\xc2\xa0/ /g'` in GNU sed should work to replace them with regular spaces.

Comment: I have tried `sed -e 's/[[:cntrl:]]/ /g' file.txt ` but I wonder why it doesn't work.

Comment: @OK-Validation `cntrl` doesn't include the necessary characters. See https://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html

Comment: You could _probably_ use `[^[:graph:][:blank:]]` to match any non-printing, non-space, non-tab, character. But I don't know how it plays with locales. Matching specific bytes is probably better, but do you need `LC_ALL=C`?

Comment: @they Thanks for your solution. `LC_CTYPE=C sed 's/[^[:graph:][:blank:]]/ /g'` does the job on my system.

Comment: @SebMa if you feed UTF-8 text to that sed running in the C locale, it would trash any non-ASCII character, starting with e.g. `é` and `ä`. That would be a pretty big problem for a few languages.

Comment: @ilkkachu Thanks. So maybe, I'll stick to `sed 's/\xC2\xA0/ /g'` instead.

Comment: @SebMa, yeah. The non-breaking space is a bit hard to catch with the character classes anyway, it's in `[:punct:]` along with `:-,.` etc. on GNU, and (so I hear) in `[:blank:]` along with the space on BSDs. Changing all of `[:blank:]` to spaces might make sense, but trashing punctuation doesn't seem too useful. Then of course there's piles of other Unicode space-like characters too (but they're more likely to be in `[:blank:]`).

Answer (score 1):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
raku -pe 's:g/\c[NO-BREAK SPACE]/ /;'  file.txt
```

Here are solutions coded in Raku, a member of the Perl-family of programming languages. An advantage of Raku is high-level support for Unicode out-of-the-box, no external libraries/packages/modules necessary.

Above I just use the 'official' Unicode name for `&nbsp`, which can be entered into the familiar `s///` substitution operator as `\c[NO-BREAK SPACE]` (see https://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0080.pdf).

But the `\c[NBSP]` name-alias below also works:

```perl
raku -pe 's:g/\c[NBSP]/ /;'  file.txt
```

Finally, entering hex also works:

```perl
raku -pe 's:g/\x00A0/ /;' file.txt
```

For further information on Unicode support in Raku, see below.

https://www.codesections.com/blog/raku-unicode/
https://docs.raku.org/language/unicode

Comment: Is `\x00A0` the UTF-16 equivalent of `\xC2\xA0` in UTF-8 ?

Comment: @SebMa Using Raku, calling `.uniname` on `\xA0` returns `NO-BREAK SPACE`, same as `\x00A0`.  And calling `.uniname` on either `\xC2` or `\x00C2` returns
`LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH CIRCUMFLEX`.